# Django: Номер итерируемого элемента

Tags: django, views

Проект на Django **v2.0.4**
Есть модель с профилями пользователей. В ней присутствует рейтинг (формат: integer, non-unique).
**Вопрос:** при получении отсортированного списка (методом *order_by*) профилей по рейтингу я могу получить его порядковый номер в данной итерации?

*Причина по которой мне это необходимо - показывать на странице какое место занимается пользователь согласно рейтинга.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так, как вы хотите - не получится. QuerySetы в Django - это генераторы, а не списки. Вы можете использовать любой из доступных методов позволяющих искать позицию элемета в списке, преобразовав QuerySet в список.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать.

Answer (score 0):

Можете

```
for n, obj in enumerate(Profile.objects.order_by('rating')):
    ...
```

Comment: Возможно не перебирать элементы итерации, а сразу найти порядковый номер в итерации по логину?

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, вам поможет [агрегация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/)

```
from django.db.models import Count

class Profile(models.Model):
    rating = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ...

    @property
    def rank(self):
        aggregate = (Profile.objects
                            .filter(rating__lt=self.rating)
                            .aggregate(rank=Count('rating')))
        return aggregate['rank'] + 1
```

И потом в шаблоне

```
Позиция в рейтинге: {{ user.profile.rank }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно вас понял, и вам нужно выводить в шаблоне место в зависимости от рейтинга (Например 1, 2, 3, N), то есть вариант проще.

В шаблоне используем {{ forloop.counter }}:

```html
<ul>
  {% for profile in profiles %}
    <li>Место пользователя {{ profile.name }} в рейтинге: {{ forloop.counter }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Где profiles это ваш уже отсортированный queryset, profile элемент (в вашем случае пользователь, атрибут name имя пользователя, у вас могут быть другие атрибуты). forloop.counter индекс (в нашем случае начиная с 1, и увеличивающийся при каждой итерации).

Так как queryset уже отсортирован, используя {{ forloop.counter }} мы выводим место в рейтинге, при этом не преобразуем queryset в список, так как это может повлиять на производительность при масштабировании (представьте если у вас в выборке будет 1000000 + элементов).

В итоге выводим в шаблоне, правильное место в рейтинге.